# remove line from captcha image

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, image-processing, captcha

I'm scrapping captcha images from a website and converting them into text so that I can handle them, clear captcha are converted easily into text with pytesseract but captchas with line are not. Can someone help me remove the line from captcha(it is in yellow color)?
[captcha_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzmkZ.jpg)

I tried this,`

```
    image = cv2.imread('test_captcha2.png')
    image = cv2.blur(image, (3, 3))
    ret, image = cv2.threshold(image, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    image = cv2.dilate(image, np.ones((3, 1), np.uint8))
    image = cv2.erode(image, np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8))

    cv2.imshow("1", np.array(image))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but it is not removing the line